# Casting result of multiplication two positive integers to long is negative value

Tags: java, android, jvm, dalvik

I have code like this :

```
int a = 629339;
int b = 4096;
long res = a*b;
```

The result is `-1717194752`
but if I add one manual cast to long `long res = ((long)a)*b;` or `long res = (long) a*b;` the result is correct `2577772544` 
Who can explain how does it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
long res = a*b;
```

`a*b` will be treated as integer unless you add 'l' at end (or) cast.

As per [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive). For integral values, this data type is generally the default choice unless there is a reason (like the above) to choose something else.

Comment: And as I understand java doesnt cast types automaticaly to result type?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There are rules on determining the result type. Let me see if I can find that documentation for you.

Answer (score 8):

You have to break the assignment statement into its parts to understand what is doing on:

```
long res = a*b;
```

Step 1 is to get the values of `a` and `b`.

Step 2 is to evaluate `a * b`.  Since `a` and `b` are both `int`s, this is an `int` multiplication.  So we multiply `629339` by `629339` which would be `2577772544`.
Unfortunately, `2577772544` is larger than the largest possible Java `int` value ... so the multiplication operation silently *overflows* ... and we get `-1717194752` instead.

Step 3 we assign the value of the RHS to the LHS.  Since the RHS is `int` and the LHS is `float`, the JLS says we perform a *primitive widening* conversion ... which simply turns `-1717194752` into a `long` with the same value.  The widened value is then assigned to `res`.

---

To get the answer that you are expecting, we have to force multiplication to be performed using `long` arithmetic.  For example:

```
long res = ((long) a) * b;
```

In this case, we have a multiplication of a `long` by an `int`, and this is handled by widening the `int` to a `long` and performing a `long` multiply.  This no longer overflows (because `2577772544` is well below the largest `long` value), so when we finally assign the value to `res`, it is the number that you were expecting.

Comment: As i know in C++ the result of all arithmetic operation are casted to the type of result. Java dont doo this automaticaly/

Comment: In Java, the widening to the result type happens in the final assignment, and doesn't affect the way that the RHS expression is evaluated.

Comment: Also, my C++ is rusty, but I believe that C++ behaves the same way as Java in this respect.

Comment: С++ behavior depends on compiler you use.

Comment: Sigh ... thanks for reminding me of one of the reasons that I've gone off C and C++

Answer (score 7):

`a*b` is an integer, not a long.

Because it's only an integer, it has already wrapped around the 32-bit limit.
Casting this integer back to long will not magically recover that data.